Vite - How to solve "Loading module from “https://mywebsite.org/subPath/assets/index-Dq7hsn19.js” was blocked [...] MIME type (“text/html”)" error?
I migrated a Vue SPA from Vue CLI to Vite and everything is working like a charm, except for one detail.
We build URLs from our backend with the form mywebsite.org/expPerma/:id, which is then handled by vue-router like the usual routes.
But after the Vite migration, the links are broken : users land to a blank page and gets the Loading module from “https://mywebsite.org/expPerma/assets/index-Dq7hsn19.js” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”). error in the console.
Note : the links perfectly work in dev server, the issue is in production.
I looked up in the documentation, Google and the GitHub issues and could not find a fix to this problem.
I mostly tried to apply the Multi-Page App section, without success.
Thank you in advance for you help,
PS : Here is my vite.config.js file
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    typescript(),
    vue()
  ],
  base: "./",
  define: {
    global: 'globalThis'
  },
  publicDir: STATIC_DIR,
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(pathSegments, './src'),
    },
    extensions: ['.js', '.ts', '.json', '.vue'],
  },
  css: {
    preprocessorOptions: {
      scss: { additionalData: `@import "./src/assets/scss/_mixins.scss";` },
    },
  },
  build: {
    assetsInlineLimit: 0,
  },
  test: {
  },
})


Update : my researches seem to tell that the server doesn't find the js file. But I don't know why it looks it in an nonexistent expPerma/assets folder.

The result of vite build is a bunch of static files. You can check with your eyes if there's assets/index-Dq7hsn19.js on web server. It's unknown if you configured it properly. The question doesn't make sense in general and very specific to your case

The issue was in my vite.config.js file, which defined a base: "./", which was making all asset urls relative. Removing it solved the issue.
